# Create multiple questions Checkbox dynamically validate whether checked or not android

Tags: android

I have been Using API to create form checkbox for multiple questions but i was not able to validate the data for the created checkbox can anyone please help me out

```
                    JSONArray checkBoxJSONOpt = eachData.getJSONArray("lstRegisterOptions");
                    for (int j = 0; j < checkBoxJSONOpt.length(); j++) {
                        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox(SurveyDetailsActivity.this);
                        chk.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        allViewInstance.add(chk);
                        chk.setTag(checkBoxJSONOpt.getJSONObject(j).getString("QOption"));
                        chk.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
                        chk.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(SurveyDetailsActivity.this, R.color.textchoice));
                        chk.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        chk.setId(checkBoxJSONOpt.length());
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        params.topMargin = 3;
                        params.bottomMargin = 3;
                        String optionString = checkBoxJSONOpt.getJSONObject(j).getString("QOption");
                        chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                chk.setError(null);
                                String variant_name = v.getTag().toString();
                            }
                        });
                        chk.setText(optionString);
                        viewProductLayout.addView(chk, params);
                    }
                    dataModelArrayList.add("false");
                }
```

I was using above code for creating the check box for multiple questions and my respnce is

```
 {
      "lstRegisterOptions": [
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21210,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20446,
          "QOption": "కేసీఆర్ ఈటెలకు అన్యాయం చేశాడు",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21211,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20446,
          "QOption": "ఈటెల కేసీఆర్ కి అన్యాయం చేశాడు",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21212,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20446,
          "QOption": "ఇద్దరు కలిసి ప్రజలకు అన్యాయం చేస్తున్నారు",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21213,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20446,
          "QOption": "తెలియదు",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
      ],
      "RId": 0,
      "RegisterFieldId": 20446,
      "FormId": 20145,
      "FormName": null,
      "Name": "ఎవరు ఎవరికి అన్యాయం చేశారు అని మీరు భావిస్తున్నారు.?",
      "HelpText": "",
      "QuestionType": "checkbox",
      "DisplayOrder": 8,
      "IsRequired": true,
      "ValidationType": "",
      "Options": null,
      "UpdatedBy": "admin",
      "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Answers": null,
      "LabelName": "ఎవరు ఎవరికి అన్యాయం చేశారు అని మీరు భావిస్తున్నారు.?",
      "IsInResult": "No",
      "Field1": "",
      "Field2": "",
      "Field3": ""
    },
    {
      "lstRegisterOptions": [
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21233,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20449,
          "QOption": "కళ్యాణలక్ష్మి ",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21234,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20449,
          "QOption": "షాదీ ముబారక్ ",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21235,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20449,
          "QOption": "కె.సి.ఆర్‌. కిట్‌ ",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21236,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20449,
          "QOption": "ఆసరా ఫింఛను ",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21237,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20449,
          "QOption": "\tరుణ మాఫీ పథకం",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21238,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20449,
          "QOption": "రైతుబంధు పథకం",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21239,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20449,
          "QOption": "రైతు భీమా",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21240,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20449,
          "QOption": "గొర్రెల పంపిణీ పథకం",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "RId": 0,
          "RegisterOptionId": 21241,
          "RegisterFieldId": 20449,
          "QOption": "దళితబంధు పథకం",
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
      ],
      "RId": 0,
      "RegisterFieldId": 20449,
      "FormId": 20145,
      "FormName": null,
      "Name": "తెరాస ప్రభుత్వం ద్వారా మీరు లబ్దిదరుడా?",
      "HelpText": "",
      "QuestionType": "checkbox",
      "DisplayOrder": 9,
      "IsRequired": true,
      "ValidationType": "",
      "Options": null,
      "UpdatedBy": "admin",
      "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Answers": null,
      "LabelName": "తెరాస ప్రభుత్వం ద్వారా మీరు లబ్దిదరుడా?",
      "IsInResult": "No",
      "Field1": "",
      "Field2": "",
      "Field3": ""
    }
```

this is my above responce which i was getting from api i need help to create checkbox for the above responce dynamically and validate it

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is. But if you want to listen to checkbox state changes you need to use setOnCheckedChangeListener and not setOnClickListener.

Comment: i have 2 question of checkbox in which for 1 question it has 4 checkboxx and in 2nd question it has 7 checkbox so when i was trying to validate its not getting worked it only validationg 1st 2 checkbox of 1st question its not moving to 2nd question

Comment: Are the checkboxes added to UI ?

Comment: yes they are added

Comment: Something looks odd in your JSON. Make sure it follows the format you expect.